# Docker login in windows server fails over SSH

Tags: windows, docker, ssh, devops, pipeline

I get this error, or similar, when ssh to an windows server and execute "docker login" command,the landing shell when ssh to the windows server is "CMD":

"Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."`

Why is this so complicated? How can I work around this such that I will be able to login,pull,push docker images?

I tried to pass the credentials as environmental variables,but it also throwed the same error.The issue is only when remotly ssh to the windows server.